# Spring MVC: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I'm getting a very long nested exception, the last one being:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at ...
```

Here's my DAO

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import ar.edu.itba.paw.FileUploadDao;
import ar.edu.itba.paw.models.UploadFile;

@Repository
public class FileUploadDAOImpl implements FileUploadDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public FileUploadDAOImpl() {
    }

    public FileUploadDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(UploadFile uploadFile) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(uploadFile);
    }
}
```

Here's my pom.xml inside the persistence folder where the DAO is.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>ar.edu.itba.paw</groupId>
        <artifactId>paw2018b</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>ar.edu.itba.paw</groupId>
    <artifactId>interfaces</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>interfaces</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.edu.itba.paw</groupId>
            <artifactId>models</artifactId>
            <version>${parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The pom.xml father includes:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Inside WebConfig.java I got this:

```
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "fileUploadDao")
    public FileUploadDao getUserDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new FileUploadDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver getCommonsMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520);   // 20MB
        multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);  // 1MB
        return multipartResolver;
    }
```

I don't have a deep understanding of spring/hibernate. 
I was actually following this: https://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-with-spring-mvc-and-hibernate

I'm using postgresql.

Any other code I should show please tell me.

Comment: You have the Hibernate library available to your program, but you're not actually creating a `SessionFactory` object that Spring uses as a bean. If you're starting out, I highly recommend using Spring Boot, Hibernate's JPA interface, and Spring Data JPA (which autogenerates DAOs for you).

Comment: @chrylis I do use a SessionFactory object in my WebConfig.java file, I don't know if that changes something. I followed the tutorial above and it doesn't create a SessionFactory object either.

Comment: In the configuration you showed, your `@Bean` method is saying that it *needs* a `SessionFactory`, but you didn't show anywhere that you *provide* a `SessionFactory`. (Spring Boot will do this for you automatically if you don't provide your own.)

Comment: @chrylis okay, so where can I see the dependencies I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following dependencies to pom,

```
(Assuming you're using mysql)
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version><!--version--></version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Ans a proper connection pool,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.55</version>
</dependency>
```

Since you are using java config, try defining `SessionFactory` as a `@Bean`.

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
   LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
   sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
   sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
       new String[] { "base.package.to.scan" }
   );
   sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

   return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource restDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("drivr");
    dataSource.setUrl("url"));
    dataSource.setUsername("uname");
    dataSource.setPassword("passwd");
    return dataSource;
}

Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", create);
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dielect_to_use);
        }
    };
}
```

You might also need transaction manager too,

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
    SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
    return txManager;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Uhm I can't get LocalSessionFactoryBean resolved. Do I need to add some dependencies?

Comment: @Stackoverflowed i missed that, add spring-orm to pom, it contains LocalSessionFactoryBean in package hibernate4

Comment: Ok it seems to have fixed that error. I also had to reorder some of the files of my folder. I got some other issues I asked in another question. Thank you!

Comment: What's the point of `sessionFactory` argument in `HibernateTransactionManager`? It's never used

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the sessionFactory bean, you can take a look below example. (dataSoure is used with oracle jdbc support)

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:sid" />
        <property name="user" value="name" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
            <props merge="default">
                <prop key="InitialLimit">7</prop>
                <prop key="MinLimit">3</prop>
                <prop key="MaxLimit">100</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean
        id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>your.package</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property
            name="dataSource"
            ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```